# How to generate .appxupload file?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-store, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to build a package for Release on ARM CPU.

When I built it with `"Compile with .NET Native tool chain"` checked, the package failed to build and threw me an error which states `error : ILT0021: Could not resolve method 'System.Nullable<System.Double> $95_Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.get_DiagonalSizeInInches()'`.

When I built it with `"Compile with .NET Native tool chain"` unchecked, there are no error and the package were successfully created, BUT the compiler generates the .appx file. For Windows Store to accept the app package, the package have to be .appxupload.

I am supposed to upload the app package today, anybody have ever experienced this kind of problem? If so, please teach me how to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Just in case this helps, here is my extensions/external libraries;
-AdDuplexWin10, 
-Analyzers, 
-Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform, 
-Universal Windows, 
-Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP

And, I did not use Template10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my Visual Studio, what has changes is that I can change Project > App Properties > Application > Target Version to "Build 10586" from "Build 10240". After done all these, I can build the package successfully. It seems that the `error : ILT0021: Could not resolve method 'System.Nullable<System.Double> $95_Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.get_DiagonalSizeInInches()` is only for the build 10240... I hope this problem will not rise again :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm that you're generate the package by the same way as here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx ?

For the .NET Native error, it could happen because of an external library you're using in your project, I've seen a couple of issues like this related to some libraries..

Comment: my external libraries are AdDuplexWin10, Analyzers, Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform, Universal Windows, Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP.. I want to release the app for mobile devices (ARM).. is there something that I should remove? 

and Yes, I can confirm you that I have tried generate the package the same way as the link you provided, but I received an error.